# Is it possible to reinstall windows 8 upgrade on the SAME machine? (Clean Install)

Tags: windows-8, reinstall, spyware, keylogger

I purchased the Windows 8 upgrade back in December. I've had it installed for a month now and am completely satisfied with the product.

Although, just recently my ex-roommate confessed to me that he installed spyware/keylogger software on my computer to spy on me and make sure I wasn't talking to his girlfriend.

Anyway, all drama aside, so far I've spent roughly $140 on anti-virus programs to try and clean my PC. I went through countless hours trying to quarantine my PC, but I haven't had any luck in doing so.

Before spending any further amount trying to resolve this security issue with my PC I would like to find out if this alternative option is possible.

Please, if anyone here knows if this will work, I'd like to completely reformat my PC and install the same Windows 8 OS upgrade (clean install) for the same computer.

Thank you, for any answers, in advance.

Comment: Since you have Win8, why not use the in-built [reset](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) feature? (Note: reset, not refresh.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say yes.....Give it a try, I believe there is an option for a fresh install (it might leave your old installation in c:\windows.old which you can delete after the installation).

And of course, secure your computer and don't leave it open when idle.  A good password wouldn't hurt either.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you, MDPC. I might as well go ahead and try that right now. I appreciate the reply, completely forgot about the windows.old folder option that leaves it behind. P.S. I've always had a strong password, I just happen to have a habit of leaving my computer on while away. Anyway, take care. :)